# why this code not work? can you help me?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

why this code not work?

my model

```
 public function get_question_by_testid($id) {
    $this->db->select('question, description, name');
    $this->db->from('question');
    $this->db->join('test', 'test.id = question.testid');

    $this->db->where('testid', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count) || $count > 1) {
        $question = null;
        return $question;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

why this code not work?

```
 //controller function test($id = NULL) {

    $data['tests'] = $this->student_model->get_test_by_id($id);
    $data['questions'] = $this->student_model->get_question_by_testid($id);
    $this->load->view('studentExam',$data);
}
```

why does this code not work?

```
//view
foreach ($tests as $test)
{
    echo $test['name'];
    echo '</br>';
    echo $test['description'];
 }

 foreach ($questions as $question) {
     echo $question['test'];
     echo $question['question'];
     echo '</br>';

 }
```

Comment: may be because of same `table name` and `column` name.

Comment: why this code not work :p  why :)   show your error message

Comment: I think you need to add ! at `if (!empty($count) || $count > 1)`

Comment: do you get any errors when you run thi scode?

Comment: this is error  Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() –

Comment: Better you check whether the questions array is empty or not, just before looping it. If it's empty, then no need of foreach...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line:

```
$this->db->where('testid', $id);
```

To this:

```
$this->db->where('question.testid', $id);
```